# How do I get the 16-byte representation of my GitHub public key from my .pub file?

Tags: git, github, public-key, rsa, private-key

In my GitHub settings, it lists my public keys as 16-byte hexadecimal:

```
01:23:45:67:89:AB:CD:EF:01:23:45:67:89:AB:CD:EF
```

Sadly, GitHub for Windows is buggy and keeps making me new github_rsa/github_rsa.pub files. I want to keep the one I have and remove the other two from my Account Settings, but how do I figure out that representation from the .pub file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With OpenSSH you would use the the `ssh-keygen` command like below to find the fingerprint for a public key.

```
ssh-keygen -l -f .ssh/id_rsa.pub
4096 79:53:3a:31:56:e4:61:d3:bc:44:ad:a4:ec:8f:6f:1b zoredache_id (RSA)
```